# PHP preg_replace error wordpress

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following wordpress code

```
function shortcode_parse_atts($text) {
    $atts = array();
    $pattern = '/(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"(?:\s|$)|(\w+)\s*=\s*\'([^\']*)\'(?:\s|$)|(\w+)\s*=\s*([^\s\'"]+)(?:\s|$)|"([^"]*)"(?:\s|$)|(\S+)(?:\s|$)/';
    $text = preg_replace("/[\x{00a0}\x{200b}]+/u", " ", $text);
    if ( preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
        foreach ($match as $m) {
            if (!empty($m[1]))
                $atts[strtolower($m[1])] = stripcslashes($m[2]);
            elseif (!empty($m[3]))
                $atts[strtolower($m[3])] = stripcslashes($m[4]);
            elseif (!empty($m[5]))
                $atts[strtolower($m[5])] = stripcslashes($m[6]);
            elseif (isset($m[7]) and strlen($m[7]))
                $atts[] = stripcslashes($m[7]);
            elseif (isset($m[8]))
                $atts[] = stripcslashes($m[8]);
        }
    } else {
        $atts = ltrim($text);
    }
    return $atts;
}
```

After I execute the function with a path, I get this error:

> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1 in /PATH/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 258

Line 258 marked here

```
$text = preg_replace("/[\x{00a0}\x{200b}]+/u", " ", $text); //<--- LINE 258
```

can anyone provide any help with this?

would be appreciated

Cant downgrade php version...

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but you may also try `\\x{hhhh}` instead of `\x{hhhh}` in double quote.

Comment: check this one: [incorrect-pcre-version][1]. May be there is some answer to your problem here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323228/phpinfo-is-reporting-incorrect-pcre-version

Answer (score 1):

That happens because your PCRE is outdated. After updating PHP to 5.3 version, you need to manually update the PCRE of your server.

Run the following code in your SSH:

```
pcretest -C
```

It will show you the version your running of it. The last version is 8.32.

Here is a relation of the PCRE version you should use with each PHP version:
http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php